# Gwan, failed to map segment

Tags: centos, compatibility, permission-denied, g-wan, tmp

I am having trouble with **Gwan**, I have used is successfully without hiccup on several machines but having trouble with my current machine CentOS 6.3 64bit Final, gwan version 3.12.26, glibc version 2.12 (stable) from gwan.

Whenever I try and start gwan `./gwan`

It returns back with

```
Linking loan.c: failed to map segment from shared object: Operation not permitted
```

I have full root access, have made sure that all `.so` shared files are executable, and ensured that SELinux was OFF.

Anything you all can shed some light on would be great

Comment: That's most probably an access rights issue for temporary files. If /tmp is mounted with the noexec option then you will have to define a $TMPDIR environment variable with more permissive rights, see the G-WAN FAQ: http://gwan.ch/faq#error8246

Answer (score 0):

There are stability issues on version 3.12.26 due to GLIBC wrappers and direct system calls. The issues are different on different OS/GLIBC that's why it's working on some machines and not working on others.

I will suggest to use 3.3 (If you have it) for now until version 4 is released.

Comment: Great answer Richard - We were so dismayed with GLIBC's failure to benefit from G-WAN's wrappers aimed at patching its flaws that we completely removed G-WAN's dependency on GLIBC by implementing the remaining syscalls and the few needed libc functions. As a result, **G-WAN will now be PORTABLE on all Linux releases since 2003** in addition to be even smaller and faster.

Comment: I downloaded the 3.3 version but the same problem as above persists, still have root access and SELinux off, and have an updated version of GLIBC

Comment: If **/tmp** is mounted with the **noexec** option then you will have to define a $TMPDIR environment variable with more permissive rights, see the G-WAN FAQ: http://gwan.ch/faq#error8246

Answer (score -2):

**Richard Heath**, give the link to download 3.3 version! Why all advices about G-WAN so uninformative? It's all like bla bla bla. I explore the whole gwan.com website. Only link to download latest version!

Comment: I got copies of V3.3 32/64 bit. I can send it to you if you say please.

Comment: Richard gave you the technical answer to your technical question. That's informative and pretending the contrary *is* disinformation.

Comment: Richard, it would be perfect if you can upload it anywhere.

Comment: @user1940518 I will add it on my site tonight.

Comment: @Gil Tell me if I am not allowed to do it. I will take the links down.

Comment: G-WAN is a *freeware*, so you can distribute it from any site without asking the permission. G-WAN v4 will be so much better than people will no longer want to use v3, but hey, that's the purpose of new releases  =)

Comment: @user1940518 here is the link for 3.3.28 download http://www.mnd22.com/blog/g-wan_version_3.3.28_download

Comment: Well ehm, scared. I dont see PHP supported here o_O

Comment: PHP is not natively supported on version 3.3

Comment: Yeah, i understand. I'll wait for v4 because most of my current apps is on PHP, unfortunely.